# Dynamically bind values from qml to repeater created object

Tags: qt, qml

I control the position of some elements of my scene using alias properties likes this : If I have a file  `Foo.qml` containing

```
Item {
  property alias myprop1: id1
  property alias myprop2: id2
  Node {id:id1,...}
  Node {id:id2,...}
```

On my main, I can then call

```
Slider{
  id:myslider
}
foo{
  myprop1.x: myslider.value
}
```

Now if my Foo.qml contains an unknow number of properties (lets say they are all called `mypropX`). If I have 10 properties I want to create 10 sliders, one for each property. It is possible with a repeater and loop like mentioned in last answer [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/70777/qml-list-all-variables-like-in-a-loop-or-something-else/3)

```
Foo{
  id:myfoo
}
Column {
    Repeater {
        id: myrepeater
        delegate: Slider {
            from:0
            to:400
            y: 12*index
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            let propArray = [];
            for(var prop in myfoo){
                //select only the properties I'm interested in
                //a "onXXXChanged" is created on each properties so I also have to remove it
                if(prop.substring(0, 6)==="myprop" && prop.substring(prop.length-7,prop.length)!=="Changed"){
                    propArray.push(prop)
                }
            }
            myrepeater.model = propArray
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is now that I don't know how to bind those 10 sliders to my properties.
I tried adding to my Foo instance in main

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    let i=0
    for(var prop in myfoo){
        if(prop.substring(0, 6)==="myprop" && prop.substring(prop.length-7,prop.length)!=="Changed"){
            //equivalent to myprop1.x: myslider.value when there was no repeater
            myfoo.prop.x = Qt.binding(function() {
                return myrepeater.itemAt(i).value
            })
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

But it return

```
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
qrc:/main.qml:145: Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "prop"
```

The problem is that in the for loop, `prop` is a string. I am also not sure that at the moment the onCompleted is executed, the repeater has already created all the slidders.

I could use the QML type `Bindings{}` which takes a target (`myrepeater.itemAt(i).value`) and the property name as a **string**, but I don't know how to call the `Bindings{}` type from javascript

Comment: You can use the [] operator, so `myfoo[prop]` if I'm reading this correct

Comment: that solves the `non-existent property` problem. Now have the first error message : `QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext` is still there

Comment: That I cannot examine from the given code. Do you have an idea on which line it happens?

Comment: It is the `myfoo[prop].x = Qt.binding(...` that raises this error

Comment: apparently, it is a warning and not an error. I also get this warning when I try to invoke `Qt.bindings` on other component, and the binding works. Yet here, my slider still don't control my Foo position

Comment: You can also try to use a `Binding` object

Comment: In this case, how can I create all my Binding object, each being different (eg target is not the same) ? Creating a repeater with Binding{} as delegate seems weird

Comment: It turns out that is what I wanted to do. All binding objects, no javascript for binding. The delegate of my repeater is an item containing the slidder + a binding object `Binding {target: myfoo[modelData]; property: "width"; value: slider.value }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [] operator to read the properties from `myfoo` and as discussed I would use a `Binding` object inside the delegate:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        id: myfoo

        property int myprop_upper_threshold
        onMyprop_upper_thresholdChanged: console.log("upper_threshold", myprop_upper_threshold)
        property int myprop_lower_threshold
        onMyprop_lower_thresholdChanged: console.log("lower_threshold", myprop_lower_threshold)
    }

    ColumnLayout {

        Repeater {
            id: myrepeater
            delegate: Slider {
                id: myslider
                from: 0
                to: 400

                Text {
                    text: modelData
                }

                Binding {
                    target: myfoo
                    property: modelData
                    value: myslider.value
                }
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                let propArray = [];
                for(var prop in myfoo)
                {
                    //select only the properties I'm interested in
                    //a "onXXXChanged" is created on each properties so I also have to remove it
                    if(prop.substring(0, 6)==="myprop" && prop.substring(prop.length-7,prop.length)!=="Changed")
                    {
                        propArray.push(prop)
                    }
                }
                myrepeater.model = propArray
            }
        }
    }
}
```